# Angular controller not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 tabs which should show the corresponding information when clicked:

```
<section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(1) }">
      <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)">Description</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(2) }">
      <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(2)">Specifications</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(3) }">
      <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(3)">Reviews</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
{{tab}}
</section>

<div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)">
  <h4>Description</h4>
  <p>{{product.description}}</p>
</div>
<div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(2)">
  <h4>Specifications</h4>
  <blockquote>{{product.specification}}</blockquote>
</div>
<div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(3)">
  <h4>Reviews</h4>
  <blockquote>{{product.review}}</blockquote>
</div>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
app.controller('PanelController', function(){
    this.tab = 1;

    this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
        this.tab = setTab;
    };
    this.isSelected = function(checkTab){
        return this.tab === checkTab;
    };
});
```

When I click on the tabs, the information does not show (for example; the {{product.description}} does not show my description). I have tested the code in developer tools, and it tells me that 'this.tab' in the controller does in-fact change to the corresponding tab number when the different tabs are selected, but I cannot figure out why my information is not showing.

Before I added the tabs to my application, the {{product.description}} etc. were working perfectly, however it now does not show when tabs are selected.

Comment: Your tabs are outside the controller element (ie `<section>`). They do not have access to the controller instance there

Comment: you `div` of displaying productions are out of `section` which you bind with ng-controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things that are causing that issue

You are using as syntax which means that in controller you have to do this:

```
app.controller('PanelController', function(){
    var panel=this;
    panel.tab = 1;

    panel.selectTab = function(setTab) {
        panel.tab = setTab;
    };
    panel.isSelected = function(checkTab){
        return panel.tab === checkTab;
    };
});
```

And in your html bring ur class panel divs under section tab as they are outside the scope of the controller as per your html like below

```
   <section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(1) }">
          <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)">Description</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(2) }">
          <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(2)">Specifications</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(3) }">
          <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(3)">Reviews</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    {{tab}}

<div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)">
      <h4>Description</h4>
      <p>{{product.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(2)">
      <h4>Specifications</h4>
      <blockquote>{{product.specification}}</blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(3)">
      <h4>Reviews</h4>
      <blockquote>{{product.review}}</blockquote>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code.

> 1. your panel divs are outside controller div
> 2. you should use this.panel = 1; not this.tab

```js
var app= angular.module('newApp',[]);
app.controller('PanelController', function(){
    this.panel = 1;

    this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
        this.panel = setTab;
    };
    this.isSelected = function(checkTab){
        return this.panel === checkTab;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="newApp">
<section ng-controller="PanelController as panel">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(1) }">
      <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(1)">Description</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(2) }">
      <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(2)">Specifications</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:panel.isSelected(3) }">
      <a href ng-click="panel.selectTab(3)">Reviews</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
{{tab}}
<div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)">
  <h4>Description</h4>
  <p>{{product.description}}</p>
</div>
<div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(2)">
  <h4>Specifications</h4>
  <blockquote>{{product.specification}}</blockquote>
</div>
<div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(3)">
  <h4>Reviews</h4>
  <blockquote>{{product.review}}</blockquote>
</div>
</section>



</div>
```